# Async timer function blocks itself when called twice

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, discord.py

I'm currently trying to implement a function to my Discord Bot where I can easily delete the sent message after a set amount of seconds.

Here is my function:

```
async def messageCountdown(context, message, counter):

    response = await context.send(f"**{'—' * counter}** \n {message}")

    for i in range(counter, 0, -1):
        await response.edit(content=f"**{'—' * i}** \n {message}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    
    await context.message.delete()
    await response.delete()
```

Function call:

```
@client.command()
async def test(context, *message):
    await messageCountdown(context, "Test", 10)
```

The function itself runs totally fine if only called once:
https://gyazo.com/3b1eef9ecf8ecbe6473e8b20dfcd19d1 
As soon as I call it twice or more often, the countdown goes down inconsistently in a weird way: https://gyazo.com/af4b23c5831ae90d5bc5a8461a22b0d7

I tried the same again but replaced `await asyncio.sleep(1)` with `time.sleep(1)`, same result.
This is where I don't know how to continue, as all I found was that `asyncio` should solve the problem, which it obviously doesn't. Also, I don't understand why one function blocks the opposite function since neither asyncio nor time should do so as the function is asynchronous (which should exactly prevent what happens right now, shouldn't it?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with the `async` function here. The problem is Discord API Rate Limits

You call the function twice so it does edit message twice every second instead of once.

Once you hit the rate limit the bot does the thing but it isn't yet updated due to rate limit, as soon as the rate limit is removed it instantly updates the message which causes it to jump from step 3 to step 1 directly, resulting in inconsistent updation of message.

Read More about Discord API Rate Limits: [`here`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits)